# How Do I Space Out the Labels on the Y axis in ggplot2?

Tags: r

I need to increase the spacing between my labels on the y-axis (see picture below).  I have also included the code that I have used to make the plot in ggplot2.

Thanks for your help!

```r
ggplot(who6, aes(total_cases, country))+geom_col(width = .25, position = position_dodge(width = 60*60*24))
```

[image]

Comment: How i can see, it is your rmarkdown?

Comment: And don't forget to add how you make "who6" dataset.

Comment: thanks, Manro!  Is there a way to change the rmarkdown to correctly display the plot?

Comment: also, this is how I made "who6:```{r}
who6<-who5%>% 
  group_by(country)%>%
  summarize(total_cases = sum(cases))%>%
  arrange(desc(total_cases))%>%
  filter(total_cases > 100000)
view(who6)
```

Comment: ... but how did you get who5, 4... add all steps to your question. I can't reproduce without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)
```

It should alternate the horizontal placement of the labels so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your example, but in the next time don't forget to add it by yourself.

I think, you should do that:

```
***
plot_new <- ggplot(who6, aes(total_cases, country)) +
       geom_col() + theme (axis.text.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "mm"), angle = 90)) + coord_flip()
***
```

Now your plot will look better:

[image]